MySQL: Index invalid when selecting by a random id
There's a table:
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,

When I'm processing the flowing statement (There's more than 1000 records in this table), a table scan is processed. Why primary key index does not work?
SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE id = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 1000)


And sometimes there are 2 different results, why would this happen?

index invalid when MySQL selects by random id and sometimes return two different values

Because the value of RAND() is different for each row in the request, a full table scan needs to be performed, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/ftD6TiHy

Well, I think this is the answer, thx!

When doing this:
WITH abc AS (SELECT FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 1000) as  R)
SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE id = (SELECT R FROM abc);

You might expect that the CTE only returns one record, and the index can be used.
but when adding EXPLAIN it shows UNCACHEABLE:



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
PRIMARY
t_test
null
ALL
null
null
null
null
1024
100.00
Using where


2
UNCACHEABLE
SUBQUERY

null
system
null
null
null
null
1
100.00


3
DERIVED
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
No tables used



EDIT:
Just found this in the documentation:
The difficulties stem from the fact that the RAND() function is evaluated once for every row of the table. To avoid multiple function evaluations, use one of these techniques

Move the expression containing the nondeterministic function to a separate statement, saving the value in a variable. In the original statement, replace the expression with a reference to the variable, which the optimizer can treat as a constant value:

SET @keyval = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 49);
UPDATE t SET col_a = some_expr WHERE id = @keyval;

